# Debugging information not displayed Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I need your help due to the fact that debugging information is not shown in an Java project used with Eclipse IDE.

Root cause: exception thrown from an open jar library

Done until now:

1. Created an external Java project containing the source files from faulty library
2. Added external project to main project
3. Edited source lookup from Debug configuration and added the external project

Expected: debugging information to be shown from external project

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: Are you using JDK and not JRE?

Comment: I am using JRE.

Comment: Try using a JDK.

Comment: My debug runs fine for all other components. I'm using fragments.

Comment: Tried both (JRE and JDK) with the same result :-(

Comment: Try to add something like `-vm
C:/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javaw.exe` at the first line of your eclipse.ini file. With a "return to the line" after -vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the classes and the java source code in the same jar file and the debugging worked.